# Using cURL to get google chart images through a proxy

Tags: php, curl, proxy, google-visualization

I need to get images from Google Chart, but I'm behind a proxy.

With the code below (changing $url) I can get images from other sites, but not from google:

> $url =
>   'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=450x270&chd=t:'.$values_list.'&cht=p&chl='.$labels_list.'&chco=80AF1B,FFFF8C&chf=bg,s,F8F8F8';

```
$img = '../uploads/tx_oriindicadores/triglo.png'; 

file_put_contents($img, t3lib_div::getURL($url));
```

The code of the getURL() method uses cURL functions to connect and retrieve data.

At this moment I only get an empty file.

Are there some parameters or configuraton that I care in order to get images from google?

Thanks.

---

The getURL() method is native of TYPO3 and you can see the code in this page:
http://doc-typo3.ameos.com/4.1.0/class_8t3lib__div_8php-source.html Line 2342

I pass the parameters through the backend of the site.

Comment: @AurimasL I updated the question with more information.

Comment: Can you var_dump() the value of $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['curlUse'] immediately before the first if() branch in getURL() and paste the result here (omit any passwords and other sensitive information).

Comment: @elazar The var_dump output is ´string(1) "1"´ so the code goes through that first ´if´ of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function above is right, the problem was that in the variable `$labels_list` there were spaces. So replacing the spaces with `%20` solved the problem.

The spaces in the direct URL request are not a problem, but in cURL there are.

So as general rule don't use spaces when work with cURL, use instead `%20`.

Answer (score 1):

Try var_dump()-ing the result of the function. If it's FALSE, then you can figure out the problem by adding an
`echo curl_error($ch);` right before curl_close($ch); in the getUrl() function and post the error message.

Comment: Agreed. You might also try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`.

Comment: Thanks. I got bool(false) and the `echo curl_error($ch);` bring the message **The requested URL returned error: 400**

Comment: Using the code below I can use the error check of the method without touching the core code: `$report = array();
       file_put_contents($img, t3lib_div::getURL($url,0,FALSE,$report));
       echo $report['message'];`

Comment: Ok, it seemes the proxy doesn't like that request. Try adding a user agent to that request. Try `array('User-Agent: PHP-curl')` as the 3rd param to the getURL request. If that doesn't solve it, try it with a real browser's user agent string.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I don't think that there is an user-agent problem with the proxy, since I don't have problems using other Urls. The problem is only with Google Charts. Maybe because is a URL with params.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the url with e.g. wget --save-headers  to see what the result was.

Then change url/agent/cookie settings until you get it to work.

Then go back to PHP.

Comment: With wget --save-headers I obtained ERROR 400 Bad Request. I've never before used headers, could you suggest me which to test?

Comment: You could use this URL: `http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=450x270&chd=t:25,25,50&cht=p&chl=A|B|C&chco=80AF1B,FFFF8C&chf=bg,s,F8F8F8`

Comment: It worked with wget using the url with quotes: `wget "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=450x270&chd=t:25,25,50&cht=p&chl=A|B|C&c‌​hco=80AF1B,FFFF8C&chf=bg,s,F8F8F8"`. Now I will test with cURL.

Comment: After different tests I could identify that the problem were the use of spaces in the labels, so I replace them with %20. It was not necessary to change any thing else. And it seems that the treatment using cURL and wget are different, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

That getURL functions seems to suppress errors. Remove the error suppression (@) and a warning or two might crop up.

Comment: Thanks, but although I did that, nothing is warned.

Comment: Yes, but only see Notice and Strict Standards messages not related with my code.